# encryption algorithm for the application

Tags: delphi, encryption

What encryption algorithm is better to use? 
client-Delphi, server-Python. 
Recommend please simple algorithms and libraries ..

Comment: How secure does it need to be?

Comment: I didn't think that 'simple' and 'encryption' belonged in the same sentence. Try ROT-13?

Comment: Encryption level - protection from fool =)

Comment: Have you looked at the Cryptography API by Microsoft? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms867086.aspx

Comment: -1. This question is much too vague to be useful. In light of Eric Lippert's recent remarks, I wonder whether encryption is even what's really needed. http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/12/14/use-the-right-tool-for-the-job.aspx

Comment: Eric Lippert's article is about how easy is to design a flawed protection mechanism - and why it's better to use proven technology (and even then there could be flaws, see the recently discovered design flaw of SSL). That's exactly the mistake Embarcadero did with Datasnap 2009/2010, which pust the protection burden on the developers with just a hook to change the data stream.
And if it has to protect a client-server exchange, there is more than just the encryption algorithm (i.e. key exchange, key storage, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for simple algorithms (not simple encryption) then two come to mind:

1. [XTEA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XTEA)
2. [RC4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4)

Both are really simple and could be easily implemented in any language and both are very fast. XTEA is also secure. At least if you are not looking to protect national secrets :) I have an XTEA implementation for Delphi that works under newest delphi versions. Look [here](http://www.cromis.net/blog/downloads/).

I also found a Python version: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/496737/

Answer (score 1):

This question is far too open ended.

Your best bet for using the same library in both Delphi and Python is mcrypt. It contains a sizable cipher suite. I recommend AES / Rijndael for just about everything. It's a nice block cipher and is used almost everywhere.

Comment: if you can get blowfish, I would recommend that, it's' pretty decent, and FAST.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try the [Delphi Encryption Compendium](http://www.torry.net/authorsmore.php?id=7150). It features the most popular algorithms and is quite easy to use due to it's OO layout.